# UITableView begin/end updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When using `- (void)beginUpdates` and `- (void)endUpdates` on a UITableView do you have to make the changes to the datasource inside calls?

i.e.

If I have a `NSMutableArray` called `dataSource` driving my `tableView` could I do this...

```
// edit the actual data first
[dataSource addObject:@"Blah"];

// now update the table
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:dataSource.count - 1 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Or is it necessary to do...

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[dataSource addObject:@"Blah"];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:dataSource.count - 1 inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Just asking because I have a couple places where I am updating and I could potentially take the common code out to a function.

But only if I can update outside the update calls.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is generally a good idea to update the datasource in between tableView beginUpdates/endUpdates.  After the endUpdates is called, the OS will trigger the dataSource calls to get the sections and row counts.  If at that point, the datasource has not been updated, then you may get tableView inconsistency crashes.

It may work in some cases to update the datasource before the tableView beginUpdates/endUpdates call, however you must make sure that you are updating the datasource in the same thread and on the same run loop.  Since tableView updates must be done on the main thread, that means you have to make  your datasource updates on the main thread.

If you update the datasource, and don't immediately do your tableView updates (and you do something like rotate the screen), then you can get a tableView inconsistency crash.

Comment: where should I add these lines of code- in viewdidload? or cellforrowatindexpath? or any other method?

Comment: This is very important "you must make sure that you are updating the datasource in the same thread"

Comment: @Siyavash how can i do that? i got few delegates updating the datasource, how to make sure that im updating them in the same thread.

Answer (score 3):

I have always used 1st approach and it causes no problem. just make sure that after changing data source, immediately update your table.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this as well and don't know what the best way it is. However, the official document, [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9), does provide some info regarding this. In "**An Example of Batched Insertion and Deletion Operations**", it is mentioned:

> To insert and delete a group of rows and sections in a table view, first prepare the array (or arrays) that are the source of data for the sections and rows. After rows and sections are deleted and inserted, the resulting rows and sections are populated from this data store.

Hope this helps. And I'm eager to learn this more clearly if someone can explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

There's no rule stating that datasource updates must be within the begin/end calls. Make sure that after updating the datasource you insert/delete rows as required so as not to break things in the long term.